# How do I get the host paragraph when a paragraph is referenced in another paragraph?

Tags: 8, paragraphs

I have referenced `Paragraph B` in `Paragraph A` and in preprocess of `Paragraph B` I want to access host `paragraph A`. Is this possible with ease. As in case of paragraph references on node we can do `paragraph->getParentEntity()` ?
 I had tried same but it still get the parent node :(

Answer (score 12):

If you look at the Paragraph class in the module, you will find a public method called `getParentEntity` that return the parent entity of a Paragraph instance.

So, if you do:

```
$parent = $paragraph->getParentEntity();

if (isset($parent)) {
  // Your stuff ...
}
```

You would have the parent entity in the `$parent` variable. You can chain the method if there is multiple nested paragraphs. I also suggest using the `isset` method on the `$parent` variable because I've encounter some weird issues where random paragraphs returns `null`.

Comment: getParentEntity() returns fully loaded entity. no need to load again

Comment: Okay. I did a quick look of the code and it looked like it returned an id. Does this solve your question?

Comment: Well not really I am doing something custom to reuse paragraph Items for specific needs. For example inside a paragraph, I am referencing existing paragraph item(i.e contents of existing paragraph). End up with two paragraph templates and render them. I need something like variable sharing between those two templates to output something conditional.